# Global method in ASP.NET for an SELECT query

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, linq-to-sql, methods

I am beginner to .NET, and I am in need of creating a global method in ASP.NET so that I am able to pass a table name to it for an insert operation. I have been using Linq2SQL.

Here is what I have done so far, I have created a folder App_Code and I have added a class file in it. This is the code I have written:

```
public class Gclass  
{
    public Gclass (DataContext db)
{
        using (DataContext dbtable = new DataContext())
        {
            var _Depart = (from depart in dbtable.db select depart);
        }    
    }   
}
```

Now, in my aspx page I will call the method `class1` and pass the table name in the `db` parameter, then I will have to return `_Depart`.

I know a stored procedure is a possible way to do this, and I have used EXECUTE SQL, but I need to do this here instead.

Comment: If you're passing in a DataContext you don't need to create another one in your `using`..

Comment: Isn't it not necessary to establish a connection?

Comment: the way your class is written you would create your DataContext first and then pass it into your class. Like: `using (DataContext dbtable = new DataContext()){ Gclass gc = new Gclass(dbTable); // then use your class..}` - you need to change `class1` to `Gclass` so it becomes a constructor.

Comment: ok,if it becomes a constructor will i be able to use SELECT query for any database table? i.e (from depart in dbtable.db select depart) db should contain my table name.